# Convert elapsed real time to Date

Tags: android, date, synchronization

I'm writing a simple app to monitor sync activities on Android and am stuck with `SyncInfo.startTime` which returns a value based on `SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()`. How do I convert this value to a regular `Date` object?

Comment: This link shows a discussion on setting the base time of a `Chronometer` instance, but it doesn't allow me to set a elapsed time and retrieve the real date/time, which is what I want.

Comment: i have also search on it i dn't find right solution on this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem:

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() 
       - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
       + elapsedTime);
```

where `elapsedTime` is the time I receive from Android. As far as I've tested, this seems to return the correct date/time for an elapsed time. I'm just not very fond of this answer because Google warns not to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Unless someone has a better answer, I'm closing this question as answered.