# How to convert the Geofence expirationTime into readable format?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm creating a geofence in Android as shown in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#create-geofence-objects). The expiration duration in the example is 10 minutes, i.e. 600000 milliseconds.

```
geofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    .setRequestId("Victoria Station")
    .setCircularRegion(51.4954, -0.1443054, 500)
    .setExpirationDuration(600000)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
    .build());
```

> [public Geofence.Builder **setExpirationDuration (long durationMillis)**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder#public-geofence.builder-setexpirationduration-long-durationmillis)
> Sets the expiration duration of geofence. This geofence will be
> removed automatically after this period of time.

Later I'm checking the entered values of the geofence like this

```
Geofence geofence = geofenceList.get(0);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "expirationTime: " + geofence.getExpirationTime());
```

which results in an expirationTime of `525501519`

> [public abstract long **getExpirationTime ()**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence#public-abstract-long-getexpirationtime)
>  Returns the expiration
> elapsed realtime of geofence in milliseconds, or NEVER_EXPIRE if
> there's no expiration. When positive, this geofence will be removed
> automatically after that time.

How can I convert this expirationTime `525501519` into readable format?
Note: It is NOT a unix timestamp, which would be something like `1669823453000`...

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V., this looks great... do you like to convert this comment into an answer, so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: Thanks for the confidence. I don’t otherwise write answers on Stack Overflow any more for reasons explained in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v). On your kind request I made an exception here. Do feel free to give the bounty to someone else if other answers to the same effect are posted.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Having experienced so many odds myself, I can feel your pain. TBH, even though we communicate almost every day via comments on Q&A, I checked your profile just now after approximately 1.5 years. While reading it, I felt like crying. God bless you! You have been selflessly contributing in so many ways. Please start posting answers. From 09-Nov-2021, I did not post anything for ten months but I did not see any change in those folks whom I was not happy with; so, I decided to come back again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think it is well documented, but the time you get from `GeoFence.getExpirationTime()` is on the system clock’s elapsed real time (not measured from the epoch and also not meaning the time until expiration). So a conversion is needed.

Combining `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, with the conversion found in another answer (links at the bottom), the following could be a way to obtain a human-readable wall-clock time of the geo-fence expiration.

The code is not tested because I haven’t got an Android development environment here, so forgive if there’s a typo.

```
Instant expiration = Instant.ofEpochMilli(
    System.currentTimeMillis()
        - SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()
        + geoFence.getExpirationTime()
);

ZonedDateTime expirationTime = expiration.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String expirationString = expirationTime
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM));

System.out.println("Geo-fence expira a las: " + expirationString);
```

Example output:

> Geo-fence expira a las: 04:05:52

From the documentation of `SystemClock`:

> `elapsedRealtime()` and `elapsedRealtimeNanos()` return the time since
> the system was booted, and include deep sleep. This clock is
> guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is
> in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose
> interval timing.

So this time is the right one for an expiration. The fence will expire 10 minutes after it’s been set no matter if the device goes to sleep in the meantime or the user tampers with the clock (on the other hand, the output from above code *will* relate to the Android clock and the time the user sees on that clock, which I take for desired).

`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime()` implicitly relies upon the JVM’s current default `Locale` for producing the particular localized text, which is often a good bet for making users happy. If you want the time formatted differently, you can format the obtained `ZonedDateTime` in countless ways. Use the tutorial link at the bottom and/or search. If you are developing for older Android versions (under API level 26), the above code will require core library desugaring (link below).

### Links

- [Question: *Convert elapsed real time to Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318945/convert-elapsed-real-time-to-date)
- [Documentation of `SystemClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock)
- [Trail: Date Time (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert long into readable format. Here is the simple and straight forward solution:

```
    long milliseconds = geofence.getExpirationTime();

    final long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds);
    final long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds);
    final long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds);
    final long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(milliseconds);

    if(milliseconds < 1000){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, days +"d:" +hours+"h:" +minute+"m:" +seconds +"s:" +milliseconds +"ms");
    }
    else{
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, days +"d:" +hours % 24 +"h:" +minute % 60 +"m:" +seconds % 60 +"s");
    }
```

As per your comment use below code to convert long in to 12hr time format (Also change timezone as per your need.):

```
    Date date = new Date(115218964);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I create a geofence now using an expiration duration of `600000` milliseconds (i.e. 10 minutes), this results in an expirationTime of `115218964`, which is according to your calculation `1d:8h:0m:18s`. This result does not make any sense... it is now `1:23pm` in Costa Rica (which is GMT-6). My expectation is to get a result of `1:33pm` as expiration time (i.e. 10 minutes later than now)...

Comment: Hi @Taifun . I just updated the answer hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi @Harsh Patel, thank you again, however unfortunately it does not help... as far as I can see, the result `115218964` is not a time in milliseconds... If I use the [time pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `HH:mm:ss`, I get `08:00:18` as result, which does not make any sense... remember, `13:23` + 10 minutes would be `13:33`... and if I run a new test today at `19:41`, I get as result `224311831`, which results in `14:18:31`... remember, `19:41`+ 10 minutes would be `19:51`...